# can't send an email using laravel.? using mailtrap

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

in my projects i want when i create a user i want to send to him password and role in email through mailtrao i try many solutions but nothing happen any help .there is no errors but i can't receive mail in mailtrap !!!!!
this is my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=100eb3235f3d15
MAIL_PASSWORD=a18591922e2b38
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

and this mail.php:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Mail Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
| sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
| your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
|
| Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
|            "postmark", "log", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
| applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
| the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
|
*/

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Host Port
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
| users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
| stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
|
*/

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global "From" Address
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
| the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
| used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
|
*/

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| E-Mail Encryption Protocol
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
| the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
| transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
|
*/

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SMTP Server Username
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
| set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
| connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
|
*/

'username' => env('100eb3235f3d15'),

'password' => env('a18591922e2b38'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Sendmail System Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
| the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
| been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
|
*/

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Markdown Mail Settings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
| theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
| of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
|
*/

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log Channel
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
| if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
| for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
|
*/

'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
```

];
and this is my loginMail.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class loginMail extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
    * Create a new message instance.
    *
    * @return void
    *
    */


public function __construct($password,$role)

{
    $this->password=$password;
    $this->role=$role;

}

/**
    * Build the message.
    *
    * @return $this
    */
public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.login')->with('password','role');
}
 }
```

and this is login.blade.php:

```
@component('mail::message')
# L'equipe de ########

Bienvenue parmi notre equipe de Travail

<p>Votre Mot de passe est:{{ $password }}</p>
<p>Votre role dans notre projet est:{{ $role }}</p>


Thanks,<br> 
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

and this is my controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
     {
      //
     /**     $this->validate($request,[
            'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:20',
            'email' =>'required|string|email|unique:users',
             'password'=> 'required|string|min:6',
            'tel' => 'required|number',
            'role' => 'required'
                   ]);*/

return User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email'=> $request->email,
        'password'=> bcrypt($request->password),
        'tel'=> $request->tel,
        'role'=> $request->role

]);
Mail::to($request->email)->send(new loginMail($request->password,$request->role));
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: no errors @FouedMOUSSI

Answer (score 0):

In your `loginMail.php` construct function, you have written like this:

```
public function __construct($password,$role)

{
     $this->password=$password;
     $this->role=$role;
}
```

You are calling `$this->password` but you have not declared this variable anywhere. Please add the following lines in your `loginMail.php` inside the `loginMail` class.

```
public $password;
public $role;
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: sorry nothing change

Comment: i can't receive email

Answer (score 0):

**Sending password in email IS NOT SAFE**

Sending user's passwords **cannot be considered as safe** (even they are valid for a very short time and needs to be changed immediately during the first login).

> Besides, even if it works the user will get hashed password and will
>   not be able to login (You can't reverse the Hash).

The server should handle differently "Creating New User" flow:

1. Create new User record
2. Redirect him to login page
3. If the user can't remember his own password, you may then redirect him to reset password
   screen

Comment: in my projects this the way  of authentication the admin create users

Comment: You can send them signed reset password url instead of plain text vulnerable email